# How can I put text from a multi-line text box into one string?

Tags: c#, textbox, split, newline

I'm faced with a bit of an issue. The scenario is that I have a multi-line text box and I want to put all that text into one single string, **without** any new lines in it. This is what I have at the moment:

```
string[] values = tbxValueList.Text.Split('\n');                
            foreach (string value in values)
            {
                if (value != "" && value != " " && value != null && value != "|")
                {
                    valueList += value;
                }
            }
```

The problem is that no matter what I try and what I do, there is always a new line (at least I think?) in my string, so instead of getting:

"valuevaluevalue"

I get:

"value
value
value".

I've even tried to replace with `string.Replace` and `regex.Replace`, but alas to no avail. Please advise.

Yours sincerely,
Kevin van Zanten

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The new line needs to be "\r\n". Better still - use `Environment.NewLine`.

The code is inefficient though, you are creating numerous unnecessary strings and an unnecessary array. Simply use:

```
tbxValueList.Text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, String.Empty);
```

On another note, if you ever see yourself using the `+=` operator on a string more than a couple of times then you should probably be using a `StringBuilder`. This is because strings are [Immutable](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/strings.html).

Comment: I was approaching it completely wrong then. Instead of changing the `"\n"` bit I was messing with the results. You just relieved me of that headache, thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

Note that new lines can be up to two characters depending on the platform.

You should replace both CR/carriage-return (ASCII 13) and LF/linefeed (ASCII 10).

I wouldn't rely on localized data as David suggests (unless that was your intention); what if you're getting the text string from a different environment, such as from a DB which came from a Windows client?

I'd use:

```
tbxValueList.Text.Replace((Char)13,"").Replace((Char)10,"");
```

That replaces all occurrences of both characters independent of order.

Comment: Good point, I've never had reason to consider that before. +1

Comment: I'll keep that in mind, but for the currently project it won't be necessary. Thanks though!

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
tbxValueList.Text.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "");
```

Comment: Doh! David got there before me.

Answer (score 0):

try this one as well

```
 string[] values = tbxValueList.Text.Replace("\r\n", " ").Split(' ');
```

Comment: `tbxValueList.Text.Split("\r\n", StringSplitOptions.None);` would do the same thing. That isn't what the OP was attempting to do, it was just part of his initial solution.